# Setting renderwholetree=false breaks app

Tags: xpages, attachment

I have an xpage that has a file upload control and a save button that uploads selected file. Below that is a panel with a viewPanel that shows newly uploaded file (for that instance). I am using a viewScope.key that is being set on the afterPageLoad event. The view is filtered by this key.

It was working until I set the `renderwholetree=false` in the application properties. Current behavior is that on first save, it doesn't show but when I click on the save button again, the view panel shows the last document that was uploaded. The save just saves the doc and does a full update.

```
  <xp:button value="Save" id="button1"dojoType="dijit.form.Button">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete id="eventHandler1">
     <xp:this.action>
       <xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument>
     </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
  </xp:button>
```

I was wondering if there is any other way to fix this without setting the renderwholetree back to true again.

Any help, suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: A reason for your problem might be that the index isn't up to date after uploading the file. Try to refresh() the view panel's data source directly in the eventhandler and right after saving the document.

Comment: Thank you Mark! I tried adding this line right after the save but still didn't work. `var c:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
var nview:NotesView = c.getDataSource().getDataContainer().getView();
nview.refresh();`

Comment: Also, I'd like to note that after the first save, the first attachment doesn't show. But when I click on the save button again, page refreshes and shows the first document that was attached. 3rd save, shows first 2 docs that was attached...and so forth. There is a delay as to what docs are showing in the view.